# Regular expression from this dfa

Tags: automata, finite-automata

what will be regular express of this transition graph anyone?can make and explain this please i will be very thankful to him.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can write some equations for this:

```
(q0) = e + (q1)a + (q3)b
(q1) = (q0)a + (q2)b
(q2) = (q1)b + (q3)a
(q3) = (q0)b + (q2)a
```

You can read these equations like this: "the set of strings that leads me to state X is the set of strings that lead me to state Y followed by symbol c, or the set of strings that lead me to state Z followed by symbol d, or..."

We can now solve these equations using substitution and a rule to eliminate self-references, namely:

```
if (q) = (q)x + y, then (q) = y(x*)
```

We can start solving the system by eliminating (q3):

```
(q0) = e + (q1)a + [(q0)b + (q2)a]b
(q1) = (q0)a + (q2)b
(q2) = (q1)b + [(q0)b + (q2)a]a
```

Distributing:

```
(q0) = e + (q1)a + (q0)bb + (q2)ab
(q1) = (q0)a + (q2)b
(q2) = (q1)b + (q0)ba + (q2)aa
```

We can get rid of (q1) now:

```
(q0) = e + [(q0)a + (q2)b]a + (q0)bb + (q2)ab
(q2) = [(q0)a + (q2)b]b + (q0)ba + (q2)aa
```

Distributing:

```
(q0) = e + (q0)aa + (q2)ba + (q0)bb + (q2)ab
(q2) = (q0)ab + (q2)bb + (q0)ba + (q2)aa
```

Grouping like terms:

```
(q0) = e + (q0)(aa + bb) + (q2)(ab + ba)
(q2) = (q0)(ab + ba) + (q2)(aa + bb)
```

Using the rule to remove self-reference:

```
(q0) = (aa + bb)* + (q2)(ab + ba)(aa + bb)*
(q2) = (q0)(ab + ba)(aa + bb)*
```

Substituting to get rid of (q2):

```
(q0) = (aa + bb)* + [(q0)(ab + ba)(aa + bb)*](ab + ba)(aa + bb)*
```

Distributing:

```
(q0) = (aa + bb)* + (q0)(ab + ba)(aa + bb)*(ab + ba)(aa + bb)*
```

Using the rule for self-reference:

```
(q0) = (aa + bb)*[(ab + ba)(aa + bb)*(ab + ba)(aa + bb)*]*
```

Answer (score 0):

from the given transition diagram or DFA, equations for each state can be written as:

```
q0 = ε+q1.a+q3.b
q1 = q0.a+q2.b
q2 = q1.b+q3.a
q3 = q0.b+q2.a
```

substitute q3 in q2,

```
q2=q1.b+(q0.b+q2.a)a
q2=q2.aa+q0.ba+q1.b
```

substitute q1 in q2

```
q2=q2.aa+q0.ba+(q0.a+q2.b)b
q2=q2.aa+q0.ba+q0.ab+q2.bb
```

finally,

```
q2=q2(aa+bb)+q0(ba+ab)
```

It is in the form of t=tr+s
According to Arden's theorem,
the solution is t=sr*

```
So,q2=q0(ba+ab)(aa+bb)
```

Now substitute q3 in the equation q0,

```
q0=ε+q1.a+(q0.b+q2.a)b
q0=ε+q1.a+q0.bb+q2.ab
q0=q0.bb+(q1.a+q2.ab+ε)
```

substitute q1 in q0,

```
q0=q0.bb+(q0.a+q2.b)a+q2.ab+ε
q0=q0.bb+q0.aa+q2.ba+q2.ab+ε
q0=q0(bb+aa)+q2(ba+ab)+ε
```

Now substitute the q2 in the above equation,

```
q0=q0(bb+aa)+q0(ba+ab)(aa+bb)*(ba+ab)+ε
q0=q0((bb+aa)+(ba+ab)(aa+bb)*(ba+ab))+ε
```

Now q0 is in the form of t=tr+s so the solution is t=sr*

**q0=((bb+aa)+(ba+ab)(aa+bb)*(ab+ba))***

The Regular Expression for the given DFA is:

```
q0=((bb+aa)+(ba+ab)(aa+bb)*(ab+ba))
```